# Looping through a file and removing certain lines

Tags: bash, shell

I want to loop through a file and remove certain lines. Example file:

**test.txt**

```
a
b
c
d
```

What I have:

```
FILE=/tmp/test.txt
while read FILE
do
  # if the line starts with b delete it otherwise leave it there
  ?
done
```

Comment: The `read` reads a line from a `standard input`, not from a file what you expecting in your code. You should redirect the `stdin` getting a line from a file, see: Duffy's answer. But `sed` or `grep` is faster for this task.

Comment: @jm666 Faster for large files, but not for short ones. `fork()`/`exec()` is a lot of overhead compared to something that uses only shell builtins.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy You're right. On my notebook under 80 lines the bash is faster. Over 80 the sed is faster and over 300 lines the grep is faster as bash too. :) Depends, what do you call "large file" :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a job for [`sed`](http://www.linuxhowtos.org/System/sed_tutorial.htm) - the UNIX stream editor:

```
(sed '/^b/d' yourfile > yourfile~ && mv yourfile~ yourfile) || rm yourfile~
```

The command will delete all lines which begin with a `b` and writes the remaing lines to a backup file. If this succeed the backup file will be renamed to the original file if it fails the backup file will be deleted.

Comment: yeah actually with sed is easier to do it inplace

Comment: @DRC Only if you use non-POSIX functionality; sed's `-i` flag is nonstandard, and may not be present in all implementations. If you want a standardized editor capable of in-place operations, you'd use `ex` or `ed`, not `sed`.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy If you really have a version that doesn't support `-i` you can use: `sed '/^1/d' file2 > file2_; mv file2_ file2`

Comment: @DRC gawk 4.1.0 can change in-place too. but the one-liner looks longer than sed, because `inplace` length=7 :)

Comment: @hek2mgl Just so. It's a bug, IMHO, that this answer describes the extension-dependent way in its primary text and requires reference to comments to find the standards-compliant approach.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy will take this more into account when using sed in shell scripts. have updated the post..

Comment: Good deal. The only further change I might make would be to use `&&` rather than `;`, so that we don't overwrite the original file if the operation fails for some reason.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy But who cleans up the trash if sed fails? check my update ;)

Comment: @hek2mgl Traditionally, I've managed cleanup with an EXIT trap on the script doing the invocation, but that (like using `mktemp` to manage temporary files safely rather than using predictable names) is a bit out-of-scope here. (Predictable names are actually a potential security hole -- think of someone having access to the current directory but not to `/etc` creating a symlink from `yourfile~` to `/etc/passwd`, and putting something a lot like `/etc/passwd` in the text of `yourfile`; if the script is run by root...)

Comment: While I know about the risk of predictable file names I didn't took this in account here while I show much effort on this in other software projects.... not thought about this here... I definitely will use mktemp in my shell scripts in future! many thanks for teaching me!!! (the trap is really a bit off topic here, but of course the most reliable place for cleanup)

Answer (score 4):

you could do it with a grep oneliner :

```
grep -v "^b" test.txt > newfile
```

Answer (score 4):

Easily done with bash built-in functionality:

```
while read -r; do
  [[ $REPLY = b* ]] || printf '%s\n' "$REPLY"
done <file >file.new
mv file.new file
```

Answer (score 0):

"Perl ... it could be in your `$PATH`"  :-)

Using a `$SHELL` for tiny textual tasks (i.e. `sh`, `ksh`, `zsh`, `bash`, `tcsh`,`csh`) on BSD, OSX, Linux, AIX, Solaris with the various "standard POSIX" versus BSD, Linux and GNU extensions to `sed`, `grep` and other utilities and taking care to  account for `gawk` versus `awk` and the ancient versions of tools on many server systems ... can be hard.

```
perl -i.orig -ne 'print unless /^b/' test.txt
```

Did it work?

```
diff test.txt test.txt.orig
```

Comment: Why would anyone use `$SHELL` instead of `sh`? Part of the whole point of `sh` being POSIX-defined is that you know what you're getting. Can't use `[[ $REPLY = b* ]]` as shown in my answer, but switch to `while IFS= read -r line; do case $line in b*) :;; *) printf '%s\n' "$line"; esac; done <file >file.new; mv -- file.new file` and there you are; fully compatible with any and every standard-compliant shell.

Comment: Agreed. I'm just using `$SHELL` as shorthand for the fact that there can be different shell environments & noting that `perl` is installed in many places.

Always test before using in production ;-)